# mPDF htmlpageheader displays on Windows 10 Apache but does not on Centos 7

Tags: php, apache, mpdf

I'm transferring my program from Windows 10 Apache to a Centos 7 Server. But the PDF it generates does not display the header for the first page. The footer displays but not the header.

```
<!--mpdf
<htmlpageheader name="firstpage">
<table width="100%">
<tr>

<td width="25%" align="center"><img height="120" width="130" src="img/mcwd-logo.png"></td>

<td align="justify" width="1%"></td>

<td width="50%" style="text-align: center; color:#000000;">

<span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 12pt; font-family: CenturyGothic;"><i>Republic of the Philippines</i></span><br />
<span style="color:#365f91; font-weight: bold; font-size: 20pt; font-family: CenturyGothic;">MALAYBALAY CITY WATER DISTRICT</span><br />
<span style="font-size: 11pt; font-family: CenturyGothic;"><i>Sayre Highway, Sumpong, City of Malaybalay</i></span><br />
<span style="color:#ff0000; font-size: 11pt; font-family: CenturyGothic;"><i>Tel. No. (088) 813-2552,&nbsp;Fax No. (088) 813-5527,&nbsp;Globe 0977-837-4085</i></span><br />
<span style="color:#365f91; font-size: 11pt; font-family: CenturyGothic;"><i>Email: mcwd_malaybalay@yahoo.com</i></span><br />
<span style="color:#538135; font-size: 11pt; font-family: CenturyGothic;"><i>Website: emcwd.gov.ph</i></span>

</td>
<td width="25%" align="center"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<div style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; font-size: 8pt; text-align: left; padding-top: 3mm; ">
</htmlpageheader>


<htmlpageheader name="otherpages" style="display:none">
<div style="text-align:center"></div>
</htmlpageheader>

<htmlpagefooter name="myfooter">
<div style="border-top: 1px solid #000000; font-size: 8pt; text-align: center; padding-top: 2mm; ">
Page {PAGENO} of {nb}
</div>
<div style="font-size: 8pt; text-align: right;">
Programmed by BVTV
</div>
</htmlpagefooter>

<sethtmlpageheader name="firstpage" value="on" show-this-page="1" />
<sethtmlpageheader name="otherpages" value="on" />
<sethtmlpagefooter name="myfooter" value="on" />
mpdf-->';
```

I'm using PHP 7.1.8 and mPDF 6.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem.

Could also help others so I'll post this solution.

Since I was using PHP 7.1.8 and mPDF 6.0 but does not display my htmlpageheader, I downgraded my PHP to 5.4.16 but retained mPDF 6.0.

Successfully displayed my htmlpageheader.

What I did:

1. Follow steps, to undo all installed yum, from this link:

https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/yum-history-list-info-summary-repeat-redo-undo-new/

2. After removing all installed yum using 'yum history undo', follows steps from this link:

https://www.howtoforge.com/apache_php_mysql_on_centos_7_lamp

That's it!